# Missing element in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js

I'm new to Node.js. I'm using zombie.js to scrape a web page title from a few websites. Below is my code:

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var util = require("util");
halt = require('delayed');
title = [];
url = [ 'http://www.apple.com', 'http://www.microsoft.com', 'http://www.dell.com' ];


function getTitles(url){
    //console.log('Start scraping title');
    var length = url.length;
    console.log('Total Site to Scrape: '+length);
    label = 1;
    for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
        browser = new Browser()
        browser.runScripts = false
        browser.setMaxListeners(0);
        browser.visit(url[i], function(e, browser, status, errors) {
        browser.wait(function(){
            title[i] = browser.text('html > head > title');
            console.log(label+': '+title[i]);
            browser.close();
            label++;
        });
        });
    };  
}


getTitles(url);

halt.delay(function () {
    console.log('Array Length: '+title.length)
    console.log('Array Content: '+title)
}, 10)
```

Below is the output of the code:

```
Total Site to Scrape: 3
1: Apple
2: Dell Official Site - The Power To Do More | Dell
3: Microsoft Home Page | Devices and Services
Array Length: 4
Array Content: ,,,Microsoft Home Page | Devices and Services
```

The part that I don't understand:

1. Why is the array length returned 4 instead of 3? There are only
   three urls
2. Why is the array content only return the last element? Where are the other two missing elements?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with zombie but I am pretty sure this is a closure problem. `i` isn't what you think it is when you think it is. See this answer: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for some information on closures. Basically what's happening is your loop continues even though your requests are async, they're not done so when they come back, you've looped through all 3 URLS, now you've got three elements... well then it inserts all 3 values into the 4th element. Last one wins, so Microsoft is all you see.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit thick. Based on the top vote answer for the link that you gave me, the content of the funcs array is still not the actual value but instead:                               
Array Content: function () { console.log("My value: " + i); },function () { console.log("My value: " + i); },function () { console.log("My value: " + i); }